# JFileChooser Not Closing Correctly

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

I'm working on a project that requires the use of a jFileChooser Swing window.
The window doesn't close when "cancel" or  "open" is clicked.
After viewing a number of posts here on StackOverflow and looking at the JFileChooser [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html) and the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html), I am at a loss as to what is causing this repeating problem.

I am working with NetBeans to use its swing editor. I have also tried the program in Eclipse as a test and have received the same results.

New Update:

Here is my attempt at an SSCCE version of the code, thank you for your patience:

```
//package imi_test;

import java.io.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.*;
   
   
public class FileSelector extends JFrame {

    //private static BufferedWriter out;
    //private static FileInputStream in;
    private static String selPath;
    private int val;
    //private static UniqueReader2 ur;
        
    
    
    public FileSelector() throws IOException {
        
        initComponents();        
    }
    
    public static String getSelPath(){
        return selPath;
    }
    
  

      public static void writeNewPath(String path) throws IOException{
      //This would write the selected folder's new unique file path to a file
            System.out.println("New file path written");
        /*
        out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("recentPaths.txt",true));  
        in = new FileInputStream("recentPaths.txt");
        ur = new UniqueReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        ur.main(null);
        try{
            

            if(ur.linePres){
                                   
            }else{
                
                out.write(path);
                out.newLine();
                out.flush();
                out.close();
                                    
                FileChecker.setFilePath(path);
            }             
        }catch(Exception e){System.err.println(e);}
*/
    }
//*******************************************************
    //Netbeans auto gen GUI code starts here       

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                            
    private void initComponents() {

        jDialog1 = new javax.swing.JDialog();
        jMenuItem1 = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
        jFrame1 = new javax.swing.JFrame();

        folderSelector = new javax.swing.JFileChooser();

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jDialog1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jDialog1.getContentPane());
        jDialog1.getContentPane().setLayout(jDialog1Layout);
        jDialog1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jDialog1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        jDialog1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jDialog1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 300, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        jMenuItem1.setText("jMenuItem1");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jFrame1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jFrame1.getContentPane());
        jFrame1.getContentPane().setLayout(jFrame1Layout);
        jFrame1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jFrame1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        jFrame1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jFrame1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 300, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        folderSelector.setCurrentDirectory(new java.io.File("Computer"));
        folderSelector.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
        folderSelector.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
        folderSelector.setDialogTitle("Please Select a Folder");
        val = folderSelector.showOpenDialog(FileSelector.this);
        folderSelector.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                folderSelectorActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });


        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(folderSelector, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(folderSelector, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
        );

        pack();
    }                        


    //Netbeans auto gen GUI code ends here
//*******************************************************

    private void folderSelectorActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
       
        
        if (val== JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) { 
             try{
                 selPath = folderSelector.getSelectedFile().getPath();
                 writeNewPath(selPath);
                 this.dispose();
                 
             }catch(Exception ex){System.err.println(ex.getMessage() + "After folder selection");}
        }
        else{
           selPath = null;
           this.dispose();    
        }
    }                                              

    
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(FileSelector.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }            
        
        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try{
                    new FileSelector().setVisible(true);
                }catch(Exception e){System.err.println(e.getMessage());}
            }
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JFileChooser folderSelector;
    private javax.swing.JDialog jDialog1;
    private javax.swing.JFrame jFrame1;
    private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Thank you for your time and help with this problem.

**SOLUTION:**
After clearing out extra things from the file that netbeans put in, the jDialog, JFrame, and jMenuItem, it works the way it is supposed to.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @AndrewThompson Does this meet the SSCCE standards? Also, do you have any ideas on how I might fix this?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you should be adding an `ActionListener` to the `JFileChooser`, this is likely to (based on your code) open a new dialog each time you try and close it.

Instead you should simply open the dialog directly..

```
folderSelector = new JFileChooser(file);
folderSelector.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
folderSelector.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
folderSelector.setDialogTitle("Please Select a Folder");

int val = folderSelector.showOpenDialog(folderSelector.this);
if (val== JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) { 
    selPath = folderSelector.getSelectedFile().getPath();
}
```

This will show a dialog, which will cause the program execution to halt at this point until the dialog is closed, which you can then verify what has being selected

Comment: First, Thank you for responding.
I have just tried what you have suggested and it helped a bit.
Now when I hit the cancel, open, or "x" the window closes and reappears in the top left of the screen. After it reappears the open and cancel buttons no longer respond, though in window folder navigation still works.

Comment: @user2616684 Do you have a runnable example that demonstrates your problem.  It sounds like your problem is else where

Comment: Yes I have a standalone run-able example, but the file is rather large. I can post the files code as an edit to my question unless you'd rather I send you the file.
Also I have updated the file to the point that when I click 'open', 'cancel' or the 'X' the frame disappears, then re-appears in the top left corner of the screen without its title. The good news is that it only does this once now, the bad news is that it does not do what it is supposed to until after the second frame is closed with the same selection as the first frame was.

Comment: Please see above for my attempt at making my code into an SSCCE. If what I have edited is not in SSCCE format then I apologize. Even if it is not, it does run independently and the issue I have asked about still occurs each time

Comment: How do you ensure that your program waits on the input without ActionListner?

Comment: @JürgenK. The `showOpenDialog` is modal, it blocks the code execution at the point that the dialog is made visible until the dialog is closed, at which time it returns (and in this, returns a value indicating what the user did)

Answer (score 2):

The main problem here is that the file chooser was being *added to the frame*!  My 'learn item of the day' was that that was even **possible.**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.*;

public class FileSelector extends JFrame {

    private static String selPath;
    private int val;

    public FileSelector() throws IOException {

        initComponents();
    }

    public static String getSelPath(){
        return selPath;
    }

    public static void writeNewPath(String path) throws IOException{
        //This would write the selected folder's new unique file path to a file
        System.out.println("New file path written");
    }

    private void initComponents() {

        jDialog1 = new javax.swing.JDialog();
        jMenuItem1 = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
        jFrame1 = new javax.swing.JFrame();

        folderSelector = new javax.swing.JFileChooser();

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jDialog1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jDialog1.getContentPane());
        jDialog1.getContentPane().setLayout(jDialog1Layout);
        jDialog1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jDialog1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        jDialog1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jDialog1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 300, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        jMenuItem1.setText("jMenuItem1");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jFrame1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jFrame1.getContentPane());
        jFrame1.getContentPane().setLayout(jFrame1Layout);
        jFrame1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jFrame1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        jFrame1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jFrame1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 300, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        folderSelector.setCurrentDirectory(new java.io.File("Computer"));
        folderSelector.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
        folderSelector.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
        folderSelector.setDialogTitle("Please Select a Folder");
        val = folderSelector.showOpenDialog(FileSelector.this);

        pack();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try{
                    new FileSelector().setVisible(true);
                }catch(Exception e){System.err.println(e.getMessage());}
            }
        });
    }

    private javax.swing.JFileChooser folderSelector;
    private javax.swing.JDialog jDialog1;
    private javax.swing.JFrame jFrame1;
    private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem1;
}
```

Comment: The only difference that the above code produces for me, if it works fine for you then I have a different problem, is that the second frame that pops up is one of those empty mini frames that you get when just making an empty frame.

Comment: Works! Once I cleared out all of the extra stuff netbeans put in it worked like it was supposed to.